# Another problem with Realtek 8723BE - Module not loaded

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I just installed Mint 18.

What I have already tried:

- disabling power management: did not help
- installing lwfingers driver: broke everything, The device is now listed as UNCLAIMED when I run lshw and won't show up on ifconfig at all
- installing Pilot6's DKMS: did not help. Device is still UNCLAIMED.

`sudo rmmod rtl8723be` returns this:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module rtl8723be is not currently loaded
```

`sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be` returns this:

```
install /bin/false 
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:977 command_do() Error running install command for rtlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Operation not permitted
```

Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS, so this can't be it.

PS.: Kernel is 4.4.0-34. I also deleted the rtl8723be.conf and rebooted again, but only after everything broke, and I tried all steps again afterwards.

Comment: Mint is off-topic.

Comment: I see. I'll try their official forum then. Thanks anyway and sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the directory /etc/modprobe.d/ . If there is a file called blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf. Comment all its lines and save.Then try running

```
sudo modprobe rtl8732be
```

Then follow the steps on
https://askubuntu.com/questions/772180/wifi-not-working-on-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-adapter

Had the exact same issue on my ubuntu 16.04.